# How to fix typescript error in redux-toolkit?

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm doing a redux-toolkit tutorial with typescript.  But I'm a typescript beginner.

I don't know what the problem is here. Please give me your insight.

This is an error message.
: **TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'void | State | WritableDraft'.**

```
import {CaseReducer, createSlice, PayloadAction} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

type State = {
  value: number
}
const increment: CaseReducer<State,PayloadAction<number>> = (state, action) => state.value + action.payload; // error line

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  initialState: {
    value: 0
  },
  reducers: {
    increment,
    decrement: state => {
      state.value -= 1
    },
    incrementByAmount: (state, action) => {
      state.value += action.payload
    },
  },
})

export const {increment, decrement, incrementByAmount} = counterSlice.actions;

export default counterSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An arrow function without curly braces around it is an [implied return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#basic_syntax).  So you are returning `state.value + action.payload` which is a `number`.

Redux Toolkit allows you to either return a new state (type `State | WritableDraft<State>` at the time of this answer, or type `State | Draft<State>` in newer versions of RTK) or modify the draft state and not return anything (type `void`).  You get a Typescript error because returning `number` is neither or these.

You likely want to modify the draft state, so you need curly braces around your function body so that you aren't returning anything.

---

These three functions are all valid.  Ordered from least to most verbose:

1. You can increment the value directly using the [addition assignment operator `+=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment)

```
const increment: CaseReducer<State,PayloadAction<number>> = (state, action) => {
  state.value += action.payload;
}
```

2. You can assign a new value to the `state.value` property with [assignment operator `=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment)

```
const increment: CaseReducer<State,PayloadAction<number>> = (state, action) => {
  state.value = state.value + action.payload;
}
```

3. (Not recommended) You can return an entirely new state. I am using parentheses around curly braces to [return an object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#returning_object_literals) with the property `value`.

```
const increment: CaseReducer<State,PayloadAction<number>> = (state, action) => ({
  value: state.value + action.payload
});
```

If there were properties other than `value` you would need to copy them like `{...state, value: newValue }` which is what you see in traditional Redux reducers.  Redux Toolkit makes options 1 and 2 available so that you don't have to do this.  But if you chose to return a new state then it must be a complete state.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation!! This problem was my lack of understanding of JavaScript and Redux.

Comment: @Linda Paiste may I know what's the writabledraft is. soz I did try to find what that is but couldn't find it anywhere?

Comment: @kevinTHEprogrammer the `WritableDraft` type comes from immer, which is the package that Redux Toolkit uses under the hood for immutable updates.  `WritableDraft` used to be re-exported by Redux Toolkit, but it looks like now they have switched to using the immer `Draft` type instead.

Answer (score 0):

[`CaseReducer`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/cb0535d4ee051e8829707e711bd1583ef96d4755/src/createReducer.ts#L48-L51) return value must be `void | State | WritableDraft` while your expression:

```js
(state, action) => state.value + action.payload
```

Is a function that returns a number. The solution is to add the [`void`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) operator before the return value to set it to `undefined`.

```js
(state, action) => void (state.value += action.payload)
```

Comment: That would still do noting though.
Make it `(state, action) => { state.value += action.payload }` or `(state, action) => { state.value = state.value + action.payload }`

Comment: @phry I'm not sure what you mean, but it works in [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-surf-bzxo6?file=/src/store/todos.ts) codesandbox. Also here is the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShwFcBOA7AagewJYBMoF4oAKASgID4oA3bPAHyhQQFsAjCJAKG4GMMUAzsCgBDAIwAuWPGTpaBYmXyUauKAHIArOs59BwkQCYpcRKkxrCpChu27+Q0QGYTM8-KtLKmzkA)

Comment: It has no more type error, but it also does nothing on runtime as it adds two numbers and throws away the result. The *intention* of the question asker was to add the two numbers and reassign them to `state.value`.

Comment: @phry ooh I finally got what you mean. Thanks for correcting me. I was focusing more about fixing the type error than the logic itself.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by updating my typescript version to recommended version